# Any custom tasks I can input an optimizing compiler for efficacy studies?

Tags: linux, optimization, compiler-construction, cad

So they can be run from the Linux command line. For example, I already ported SIS CAD. Is there something else? Using an X processor and its compiler. So I'll have to port the tasks on this processor. Not interested in SPEC. Need a custom task, already implemented on other platforms and written in C (
less preferred C++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC developers [list](https://gcc.gnu.org/benchmarks) several benchmarks besides well-known SPEC CPU and EEMBC CoreMark. This page mentions [openbench](http://exactcode.com/opensource/openbench/) (the link on GCC site seems to be broken), a set of benchmarks, which is an attempt to create a free alternative to SPEC CPU.

SUSE is a major contributor of GCC project, they run [periodic C++ benchmarks](http://gcc.opensuse.org/c++bench/) to test compiler performance (i.e., both compilation speed and generated code quality).

Phoronix also offers some sort of benchmark suite, [Open Benchmarking](https://openbenchmarking.org/) (though their benchmarks are sometimes [criticized](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2014-03/msg00062.html)).